# Categorical to Numeric Variable in R

Tags: r

Create a factor vector v1 using 10 random numbers without decimals.
Convert the factor vector to numeric vector v2.
Compare v1 and v2 element-wise. Store the comparison values (true or false) in a vector, and display it.

I have tried this:

```
v1<- factor(round(runif(10)),0)
v1
v2<-as.numeric(v1)
v2
comp<-v1==v2
comp
```

Comment: Hi.  It appears that you haven't actually asked a question in your question.

Comment: I am unable to answer this question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you intended to use 0 as the second argument to `round()` in the first line of your code so your parentheses are in the wrong place. Should be `factor(round(runif(10), 0))`

Comment: By the way welcome to SO! What Dason means is that it is easier for us to help you if you clearly describe your question in a way that it is obvious what answer you are looking for. It's good that you provided code that you tried out already, thanks for that!

Comment: To convert the factor values to a numeric vector, you can't just use  'as.numeric' , instead of this use   `v2<- as.numeric(as.character(v1))`  or   `v2<- as.numeric(levels(v1))[v1]`.   And the created values are only between 0-1, I think you are aware of this.

Comment: Thank you. I too tried this.                                                                                    v1<- factor(round(runif(10,10,40),0))
v1
v2<-as.numeric(as.character(v1))
v2
comp<-v1==v2
comp

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below.

When v1 is a factor, `as.numeric(v1)` returns information on the level of each element of v1.  In this example, the first element is a 5, which is the third level of the factor so as.numeric returns 3.

The second element of v1 is 2 which is also the second level so as.numeric returns 2 and we get TRUE in the comparison v1 == v2 for that element. Also check the help `?factor`.

Using `as.numeric(as.character(v1)` does the expected conversion.

```
set.seed(2002)

v1 <- factor(round(10*runif(10),0))
v1
# [1] 5  2  9  0  9  8  8  10 10 9 
# Levels: 0 2 5 8 9 10

str(v1)
#Factor w/ 6 levels "0","2","5","8",..: 3 2 5 1 5 4 4 6 6 5

v2 <- as.numeric(v1)
v2
# [1] 3 2 5 1 5 4 4 6 6 5

v1 == v2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


v2 <- as.numeric(as.character(v1))
v1 == v2
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```